# How can I open a *.plist file from Cocos project?

Tags: android, ios, resources, plist

If i open this file in notepad i see this

resource…-utПЭЩМч)ЁЖэ3:Ќм±њNтFЧА]   Ё>¬ЖбP]э6ф—Ћ~љm

Maybe this mean - file encrypt?

I get this file from apk file.

All file in apk in folder Assets havee too.

Please help my!!!

All file in GoogleDrive

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_JZh2_rep71Q3VmeFlkdWhCYlk

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IDE like XCode, that's probably best.

You could also convert the file (assuming JSON or XML) using from command line:

```
plutil -convert xml1 file.plist
```

And then use whatever editor you like.  Convert it back with:

```
plutil -convert binary1 $file
```

You can search online for other free and commercial plist editors too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And where this command should be performed?

Comment: What kind of system do you have?

Comment: Windows. I get this resource files from the APK file and wanted only to be able to view the images.